# Scipy curve fit only giving two values when expecting four

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am currently trying to use the Scipy curve fit function to fit a hyperbolic tangent dataset with four values. However curve fit is only returning two values.  This is the code I started with:

```
def tanh(x,A,B,C,To):
    y=((A+B)/2)+((A-B)/2)*np.tanh((x-To)/(C))
    return y

parameters=curve_fit(tanh,df5.iloc[:,0],df5.iloc[:,1])
Afit=parameters[0]
Bfit=parameters[1]
Cfit=parameters[2]
Tofit=parameters[3]
```

Both numpy and curve_fit have been installed and imported correctly. I know df5 is correctly formatted as I have been able to plot the raw data in other parts of the code.

I tried changing the code to have parameters be set equal to the different fit values like so:

```
 def tanh(x,A,B,C,To):
    y=((A+B)/2)+((A-B)/2)*np.tanh((x-To)/(C))
    return y

parameters=curve_fit(tanh,df5.iloc[:,0],df5.iloc[:,1])
Afit,Bfit,Cfit,Tofit=parameters
```

I also added initial guesses to help the function narrow in on the expected values.

```
def tanh(x,A,B,C,To):
    y=((A+B)/2)+((A-B)/2)*np.tanh((x-To)/(C))
    return y

initialguess=[intA,intB,intC,intTo]
parameters=curve_fit(tanh,df5.iloc[:,0],df5.iloc[:,1],p0=initialguess)
Afit,Bfit,Cfit,Tofit=parameters
```

`
I believe the problem is in the tanh function I defined. I cannot see where I messed up and what I need to change to get it running.

Comment: Can you share df5 as well?

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html `curve_fit` returns a tuple with the optimal parameters, and the covariant estimate there. Use `parameters=curve_fit(tanh,df5.iloc[:,0],df5.iloc[:,1],p0=initialguess)[0]` if you want the parameters only

Answer (score 3):

The `curve_fit` function returns two values. The first one is an array containing the N-optimized parameters, which are what you expect the function to return, and the second one is the covariance of those parameters.

To extract the parameters the way you want to, replace

```py
parameters = curve_fit(tanh, df5.iloc[:,0], df5.iloc[:,1], p0=initialguess)
```

With

```py
parameters, _=curve_fit(tanh, df5.iloc[:,0], df5.iloc[:,1], p0=initialguess)
```

That will make `parameters = opt` and `_ = cov`, instead of `parameters = (opt, cov)`. Now, with parameters being an array of four values instead of a tuple of two, you should be able to assign four variables using it.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also assign the 4 parameters directly like this: `(a_fit, b_fit, c_fit, d_fit), _ = curve_fit(...`